# Git rebase take me to a detached commit

Tags: git

My local master branch and origin/master branch diverted by just 1 commit, and I want to rebase my master on to origin/master, so I did this:

> git rebase origin/master

This give me a conflict and I solved it and commit the change, however this take to me into a detached state.

Then I run:

```
git rebase --continue
```

It shows me this message:

```
Applying: Change endpoint url to point to new one
No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'?
If there is nothing left to stage, chances are that something else
already introduced the same changes; you might want to skip this patch.

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
```

Seems like during the rebase a patch file is generated,

What is the cause of this and what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check the message. Do the same changes already exist in the remote repository? If so, skip applying that change, like it suggests.

"If there is nothing left to stage, chances are that something else
already introduced the same changes; you might want to skip this patch."